# How do i convert NSAttributedString into HTML string?

Tags: html, cocoa, nsattributedstring

As the title tells,now i can simple convert HTML into `NSAttributedString` with `initWithHTML:documentAttributes:` , but what i want to do here is reverse.
Is there any 3rd party library to achieve this?

```
   @implementation NSAttributedString(HTML)
-(NSString *)htmlForAttributedString{
    NSArray * exclude = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"doctype",
                         @"html",
                         @"head",
                         @"body",
                         @"xml",
                         nil
                         ];
    NSDictionary * htmlAtt = [NSDictionary
                              dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                              NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute,
                              exclude,
                              NSExcludedElementsDocumentAttribute,
                              nil
                              ];
    NSError * error;
    NSData * htmlData = [self dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, [self length])
                               documentAttributes:htmlAtt error:&error
                         ];
        //NSAttributedString * htmlString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithHTML:htmlData documentAttributes:&htmlAtt];
    NSString * htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:htmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return htmlString;
}
@end
```

Comment: The title asks how to convert HTML into NSAttributeString, while the question does vice-versa.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the code you've posted? It should work.

Answer (score 45):

Use `dataFromRange:documentAttributes:` with the document type attribute (`NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute`) set to HTML (`NSHTMLTextDocumentType`):

```
NSAttributedString *s = ...;
NSDictionary *documentAttributes = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType};    
NSData *htmlData = [s dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, s.length) documentAttributes:documentAttributes error:NULL];
NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:htmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: If the text contains link, than it wont create a href for the link.

Comment: I just need Bold, Italic, Underline & StrikeThrough tags in my HTML but converting NSAttributedString to HTML outputs a lot of css to achieve this. Any alternative to keep this simple?

Comment: @ilight . did u find the solution for getting HTML tags for bold italic & underline

Comment: The biggest problem that i am facing is, when i am using this, the font size of the content is getting increased, why i dont know but it almost getting doubled

Comment: Has anyone found a way to get cleaner/custom HTML out of the `NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html` conversion?

Comment: @CliftonLabrum hi did you find an answer?

Comment: @Crashalot Unfortunately not. That appears to be something Apple has long since abandoned. I decided to pursue a different path and use Markdown instead of HTML.

Comment: @CliftonLabrum thanks for sharing! how do you convert between markdown and nsattributedstring?

Comment: @Crashalot I'm using **SwiftyMarkdown**: https://github.com/SimonFairbairn/SwiftyMarkdown. I modified it a bit to do what I needed, but it works pretty well.

Answer (score 13):

This is a swift 4 conversion of @omz answer, hope is useful to anyone landing here

```
extension NSAttributedString {
    var attributedString2Html: String? {
        do {
            let htmlData = try self.data(from: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.length), documentAttributes:[.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html]);
            return String.init(data: htmlData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        } catch {
            print("error:", error)
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```