# How to change font color, font name and font size UIWebview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

In my application I am loading HTML String which is parsed from the xml file I need to change the color, name and size of the font. To replace that I have already use the followings code but its not working

```
NSString *webString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '%d%%'", 
                      textFontSize];
    [web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:webString];
```

Is there any way then please suggest me the answer.

Thanks in Advanced!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSAttributedString` instead. Here's the [docs from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You can set the font type, colour, and size. You can then convert `NSAttributedString` back to HTML [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14165076/361247).

It's only available on iOS 6 and above.

Comment: Thanks Enrico Susatyo. I want to change everything using javascript.. is that possible other than solution

Comment: @kagmanoj the other answer is actually a lot better than mine. Try that one.