# Is there any way to convert NSAttributedString to HTML in swift?

Tags: html, ios, string, swift, nsattributedstring

I want to convert a NSAttributedString to HTML string. I've been searching how to solve it, but I have no results yet.

Any idea how can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i convert NSAttributedString into HTML string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298188/how-do-i-convert-nsattributedstring-into-html-string)

Answer (score 3):

```
let attrStr = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello World")
let documentAttributes = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType]
do {
    let htmlData = try attrStr.dataFromRange(NSMakeRange(0, attrStr.length), documentAttributes:documentAttributes)
    if let htmlString = String(data:htmlData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        print(htmlString)
    }
}
catch {
    print("error creating HTML from Attributed String")
}
```

you can use this code .it's swift example

Comment: If i want only text with html tags how can i do this? can u have any idea

Comment: The biggest problem that i am facing is, when i am using this, the font size of the content is getting increased, why i dont know but it almost getting doubled

Comment: This will not return simple html string.

Answer (score 3):

that can be wrapped in an own extension for `NSAttributedString`

```swift
// swift 5.2 

import Foundation

extension NSAttributedString {
    func toHtml() -> String? {
        let documentAttributes = [NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html]
        do {
            let htmlData = try self.data(from: NSMakeRange(0, self.length), documentAttributes:documentAttributes)
            if let htmlString = String(data:htmlData, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8) {
                return htmlString
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("error creating HTML from Attributed String")
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```