# Convert UIFont to css font style string

Tags: css, swift, uifont

I have some `UIFont`s like this:

```
let regularFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .regular)
let mediumFont  = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .medium)
```

I use them in my UIKit components like `UILabel`.

Now I want to render some text in a WKWebView using the same fonts.
I generate some html template in code but I can't figure out how to setup the css font styles to match my given UIFonts.

With some guesswork I came up with the following which kind of works for my given examples:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: '.AppleSystemUIFont'; 
                font-size: 18.0;
                font-weight: normal; 
            }
            b {
                font-family: '.AppleSystemUIFont'; 
                font-size: 18.0;
                font-weight: bolder; 
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            Regular font <b>Medium font</b> Regular font 
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works ok-ish but clearly this does not scale (how about other weights?).
Also I can already see my designer coming at me, claiming that font weight is off by .1 or something.

This is my current effort. It works on a limited subset of properties (bold, italic) but it does not handle font weight. Also I haven't tested for custom fonts yet but my guess is it won't work like that.

```
extension UIFont {
  func cssStyleString(color: UIColor) -> String {

      let colorString = "rgb( \(CIColor(color: color).red * 255), \(CIColor(color: color).green * 255), \(CIColor(color: color).blue * 255) )"
      // not sure this is right
      let fontFamily = self.fontName == self.familyName
      let fontSize = self.pointSize
      // trait is not quite right for translation into weight. suggestions?
      let fontWeight = self.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(.traitBold) ? "bold" : "normal"
      // works for italic only.
      let fontStyle = self.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(.traitItalic) ? "italic" : "normal"

      return "font-family: '\(fontFamily)'; font-size: \(fontSize); font-weight: \(fontWeight); font-style: \(fontStyle); color: \(colorString); "
  }
}
```

So hence my question:
**What is the best way to create css styles from a given UIFont, especially with respect to font weight?**

Comment: You might want to use NSAttributedString transformed into HTML to know what feature use (style, family, etc.) For instance, I got with your fonts: `font-family: '.SFUI-Regular'; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 18.00px}` &  `{font-family: '.SFUI-Medium'; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 18.00px}` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32783875/is-there-any-way-to-convert-nsattributedstring-to-html-in-swift https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298188/how-do-i-convert-nsattributedstring-into-html-string etc.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking into it. Also found this in the meantime which at least gives me a weight value – but it still needs to be converted in to css weight scale https://stackoverflow.com/a/53818276/921573