# Convert NSAttributedString to HTML with only bold and italics

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsattributedstring

I'm looking to convert an NSAttributedString into HTML, but only preserve bold and italic attributes. I don't care about font family, font size, or anything like that.

I'm basically looking to convert:
**Go** *Falcons*

to

`<b>Go</b> <em>Falcons</em>`

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There's nothing built-in for this. You will have to write your own code to handle it.

Comment: This could be helpfull : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298188/how-do-i-convert-nsattributedstring-into-html-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this can be a viable solution but one way to do this is to enumerate the attributes and go through the each segment and make your own HTML.

```
 [str enumerateAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                inRange:range
                options:NSAttributedStringEnumerationLongestEffectiveRangeNotRequired
             usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
               UIFont *currentFont = value;
               if ([currentFont.fontName rangeOfString:@"bold" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch]
                       .location != NSNotFound) {
                   //Do something with the string and range for bold? add tags and append in a different string
               } 
               // Similarly do something for for non-bold, itatlic or normal text. Keep Appending them in a string
             }];
```

Comment: This is the right general idea. But instead of looking at the font name, get the font's attributes and check its weight to see if the font is bold.