# How to decode NSAttributedString as HTML string

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, nsattributedstring

I am encoding my HTML string as attribute with the following code..

```
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                                initWithData: [itemDescribtionStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]
                                                options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType }
                                                documentAttributes: nil
                                                error: nil
                                                ];
```

How can I decode this string as an HTML string?

Comment: You posted co that appears to create an NSAttributedString from HTML. It looks like you already HAVE an HTML string. What are you asking, exactly?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, but for the reverse process: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298188/how-do-i-convert-nsattributedstring-into-html-string