# Get NSAttributedString from UITextField within NSRange

Tags: swift, uitextfield, nsattributedstring, nsrange

Let's assume I have this code:

```
let string = "This is a <b>bold</b> text"
let data = Data(string.utf8)
let attributedText = try! NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
textField.attributedText = attributedText
```

**Result:** This is a **bold** text

Now my `textField` is editable, and let's say I have my cursor here:

> This is a **bold** tex|t

You can see my cursor between **x** and **t**

I have a variable called `cursorPosition` where I store the cursor position anytime it changes and in this current case, the value of `cursorPosition` will be `18`

**Now my question:** Is there a possible way I can get all the `NSAttributedString` using `NSRange`. So I want to get all `NSAttributedString` before my cursor position using `0..<cursorPosition` and the result will be:

```
This is a <b>bold</b> tex
```

And not

```
This is a bold tex
```

Comment: What is the data type of your `cursorPosition`?

Comment: @HangarRash... It's an `Int` type

Comment: Then that makes it trivial to implement the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an attributed substring of an `NSAttributedString` using the `attributedSubstring` method.

```
let attrStr: NSAttributedString = ... // some attributed string
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: someLength)
let attrSubStr = attrStr.attributedSubstring(from: range)
```

But this is not going to give you an HTML string. This is going to give you another `NSAttributedString` representing the desired range. If you want HTML then you need to take extra steps to convert the attributed string into HTML.

Comment: Got it working, with the help of your answer, and I converted the `NSAttributedString` to `HTML` using this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50891334/5585069